takeUntil() after a filter() behaves differently from take(n) in pipe
Edit(26th September) :
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
      .pipe(
        // activatedRoute.queryParamMap emits null values first. So let's avoid it
        filter((paramMap) => paramMap && paramMap.keys.length > 0),
        tap((value) => console.log("tap", value)),
        // unsubscribe immediately if some params are found
        take(1),
        // If the params are really empty, filter will never pass. So let's unsubscribe after sometime
        takeUntil(timer(1000)),
        finalize(()=>console.log("finalize")),
        delay(1),
        combineLatestWith(this.sortableColumns$),
      )
      .subscribe(([paramMap, sortableColumns]) => {
        console.log('paramMap');
        this.setTableOptionsFromUrl(paramMap, sortableColumns);
      });

With the above code and a sample url of http://localhost:4205/inloggen (without query params)
This is the output

So why the message in tap didn't get logged but the "finalize" got printed to the console after 1 second.
So I would like to know what operators like (take, tap, delay, combineLatestWith etc.) obeys filter and what doesn't obey (takeUntil, finalize etc.)

      
      

Original:
this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
      .pipe(
        // activatedRoute.queryParamMap emits null values first. So let's avoid it
        filter((paramMap) => paramMap && paramMap.keys.length > 0),
        // unsubscribe immediately if some params are found
        take(1),
        // If the params are really empty, filter will never pass. So let's unsubscribe after sometime
        takeUntil(timer(1000)),
        delay(1),
        combineLatestWith(this.sortableColumns$),
      )
      .subscribe(([paramMap, sortableColumns]) => {
        console.log("paramMap")
        this.setTableOptionsFromUrl(paramMap, sortableColumns);
      });

I have the above code.

So take(1) unsubscribes from the source observable only when the filter passes after a valid emission from source (only when there is atleast one paramMap)
takeUntil also comes after the filter but it unsubscribes from the source irrespective of whether the filter passes or not once the timer emits

My question is,

If filter blocks the pipeline until it passes shouldn't it block takeUntil too?
If this is the expected behaviour, how can I know which operators will be blocked by the filter operator and which all will not be
If this is not the expected behaviour, how else can we achieve this?


I think what you are looking for is the RACE operator
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/race

@CaioOliveira I am not looking for any operator. My solution serves the purpose but I feel it shouldn't. I have edited my question for clarity.

If I understand correctly, what u r confused about is that takeUntil should not trigger unless something above it has emitted a value.
But it is actually intended that takeUntil will trigger regardless if it receive any emits.
Explanation:
Unlike most operators which accepts a value from the pipe chain and then performs callbacks using the value received, takeUntil does not accept any value passed from the pipe.
I want to set up a scenario to help explain:
notifier$     = timer(1000)
queryParam$   = this.activatedRoute.queryParamMap
  .pipe(
     filter((paramMap) => paramMap && paramMap.keys.length > 0),
     take(1),
     takeUntil(this.notifier$),
  )

when u subscribed to queryParam$, what rxjs does internally is, it will also subscribe to notfier$ in parellel with queryParam$, this is regardless if queryParam$ emits anything at all


maybe u might still be confused why does rxjs does it this way, so I would like to show u another use case of takeUntil.
notifier$     = fromEvent(stopButton, 'click')
oneHourTimer$ = timer(1000 * 60 * 60).pipe(
  takeUntil(this.notifier$)
)

now in this second scenario, it is possible for user to click the stopButton before the oneHourTimer$ has even emit anything at all. So in short, by subscribing both observable at the same time, takeUntil does not care if there is any value that is being passed down the pipe.

as for finalize, following the official rxjs Doc, I think its behaviour is quite straight forward.

In ur case, the queryParamMap observable is terminated by takeUntil, thus it triggers finalize

take(1) completes after the first emission.
since you have a filter before, it's logical that it completetes only after the fiter. It cannot know what comes before. You could have 100 operators before it.
takeUntil() completes when the notifier tells him to do, in this case after 1000ms. He deosn't care what comes before and after, it just completes after 1000ms.
if you think about it it's logical. Those operators are more or less indipendent from what comes before and after.

You might be missing the details. This doesn't answer the question. I edited my question to make it more clear.

i can't give you a list of all operators. You have to read the documentations. But again it makes sense, finalize calls a function when the observable completes. You can have 100 filters before. It will call the function even if the observable NEVER emitted any value. So what is the question? "what operators obeys filter?" the majority obeys this rules but not all. To find out you need to read the documentation.  For example retryand catch don't obey this rule. but it makes sense, otherwise it would be useless

Thanks. Is there any way to atleast understand which operators obey and which don't. For example the syntax, structure (the number of arguments and type of arguments passed to an operator) etc. with which we can understand such things.

i am not aware of any specific syntax or rule. if you go to learnrxjs.io the operators a grouped. I belive all the filtering and transformation operators obey the rulse. fot the others it depends
